# How can I clone a repo from GitHub using gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have a project which depends on other repos. My goal is to write a gradle task that clones the required repos automatically.

The problem I am having is that when I run my task, `gradlew` fails because it tries to compile the project dependencies before running my task. Here is what I have:

**settings.gradle**

```groovy
include ':app'
include 'testRepo'
project(':testRepo').projectDir = new File('../testRepo')
```

**build.gradle**

```groovy
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.5.1'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

build.gradle(app)

```groovy
task clone << {
    Grgit.clone(dir: file('../testRepo'), uri: "https://github.com/fakeAccount/testRepo.git")
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':testRepo')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
}
```

When I do `./gradlew clone` I get:

```groovy
"Cannot evaluate module testRepo : Configuration with name 'default' not found"
```

This is because it tries to compile the `testRepo` project before cloning from GitHub. If I take out the `compile project(':testRepo')` it works fine.

Any ideas as to how to make this work?

Comment: is testRepo in your settings.gradle ?

Comment: You have a fundamental ordering problem here.  The `dependencies` block is part of task configuration, which occurs *before* any tasks are executed.  But the thing you're depending on doesn't exist until the task is executed.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks for pointing that out. I was wondering if a task could be executed before the dependencies block. Do you think the issue you mentioned makes it impossible to acomplish my goal?

Comment: You can't run tasks before configuration ([basically by definition](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)), but you could certainly execute arbitrary Groovy code before anything else gets run.  That said, a more conventional way of solving this problem would be to build and publish a Maven/Ivy artifact from testRepo and then depend on it, or to incorporate testReo via a Git submodule or subtree.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth How can I execute groovy code before anything gets run?

Comment: Your entire Gradle file is just Groovy being executed.  So put your `Grgit.clone()` statement outside of a task, and it will just execute immediately.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That worked. But would it possible to put the Grgit.clone() in a separate file, and do something like ./gradlew run externalFile.gradle ?